# How to update time when the days are changed in calender using angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a calender and time setter. When i change the time with the time setter it is getting updated, but when i change the date the time is not getting updated. For e.g, my start date is on 7/6/2017 at 15:30 and stop is on 7/6/2017 at 16:30. Now the time is shown as 1:00. But now if i change the stop date to 7/7/2017, the time should get updated to 25:00, but it is still showing 1:00. Please help me to solve this issue.
I am here by sharing my HTML and ts code, please help

**HTML code:**
**This is HTML of time update part:**

```
<p class="text-center color-primary total-duration layout-padding">{{edit_entry.total_hours}}</p>
```

**This is HTML of calender part:**

```
<tr style="height:30px;line-height:30px;" [ngClass]="{startClass: 'start'==d.state || 'resume'==d.state, stopClass: 'stop'==d.state, breakClass: 'break'==d.state}" class="table-content" *ngFor="let d of edit_entry.times">
                                        <td>
                                            <div style="border:0;box-shadow:none;background:none;width:100px;padding:0;height:14px;text-align:center;" (click)="onStartEdit(d)">
                                                <img src="../../assets/images/icons/editicon.png" alt="edit" style="cursor:pointer;"> {{d.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="datePickers[d.state]" id="startPicker" style="width: auto;">
                                                <datepicker name="datePickerEdit" [(ngModel)]="datePickerEdit[d.state]" [showWeeks]="false" (selectionDone)="onEditDate(d,$event,edit_entry)" [maxDate]="maxDate" [minDate]="minDate" [dateDisabled]="disabledDate" ></datepicker>
                                                <div class="pickerBtns">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success  pull-right" (click)="onClose(d)">Close</button>
                                        </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
```

ts part of time update:

```
this.ApiService
      .calculateTime(edit_entry)
      .subscribe(
        time=> {
          this.timePickers[d.state] = false;
          edit_entry.total_hours = time.newTime;
        },error => {
          this.timePickers[d.state] = false;
          //console.log(error);
        })
}
```

API service of time part:

```
calculateTime(data) {
  return this.http
             .post(timerUrlBase + '/calculateTime' ,data,options)
             .map(this.extractData)
             .catch(this.handleError);
}
```